# Coldfusion app generating blank PDF page

Tags: coldfusion

We had a server migration and since the migration, a Coldfusion application is generating blank pdf pages that are able to be saved locally and printed.  The application queries a SQL Server database.  I have been through the code several times and am pretty positive the data sources are all pointed to the new environment.  I have a report from the day before the migration and all was well.  I think the paths are fine because when I changed the path, the application blew up.  I have minimal experience with Coldfusion and I am out of ideas at the moment.  What else should I be looking at when debugging this application?  Has any code been deprecated and the new environment will not run it?  Is it possible there are settings on the new server preventing this PDF from being generated?  Do I need to add a MIME somewhere that was unnecessary before?  Any advice would be helpful.  Below is some of the code being used.

```
    <cfif #qSelect.Record# EQ 0>
      <h1>Empty recordset</h1>
    <cfelse>        
 <cfdocument filename="../Reports/CustomReport.pdf" format = "pdf" orientation = "landscape" overwrite="yes">

        <h2>Database</h2>
       <cfoutput>
    <h4>Monthly Report   </h4>
 </cfoutput>      
   <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
     <tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Status</th>                    
            </tr>                
        <cfoutput query="qLocalEvents">
            <tr>
                <td>#DateFormat(qSelectEvents.EventDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
                <td>#qSelectEvents.Status#</td>
           </tr>
        </cfoutput>
        </table>
    </cfdocument>
</cfif>
```

Comment: I would start by checking if the query is returning a value.  <cfoutput> #qSelect.Record#</cfoutput>

Comment: If you temporarily comment out the cd document tag, the contents of the embedded cfoutput will display the results of your query.

Comment: To add a comment in cf is just like HTML with one extra hyphen. `<!--- <cfdocument>... --->` and `<!--- </cfdocument> --->`. Another easy way to nix a cf tag temporarily is just make sure the first two characters of the opening and closing tag is not cf... `<xcfdocument>` and `</xcfdocument>`. Bit easier than typing comments just for a quick evaluation.

Comment: If this is a query constructed with `<cfquery>`, try changing the `<cfif #qSelect.Record# EQ 0>` to `<cfif #qSelect.Recordcount# EQ 0>`, recordcount is a cf-supplied variable for queries that always has a numeric value. I'm not sure what `record` is. It may just be a typo of yours(?) but if it is blank, it will pass the test (`"" != 0` in cf)

Comment: qSelect.Record has to be the value of the record field in the 1st row of query qSelect.  Otherwise the page will throw an error.

Comment: Hi all.  Thank you for taking the time to look at the question and the responses.  The issue I have is related to restrictions in place on our server where we can't write to files in the same share.  Thanks again!